# Different user in get_current_user() and exec('whoami') for suexec virtual host

Tags: php, apache2, debian

I use SuexecUserGroup for VirtualHost

Script

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
var_dump(exec('whoami'));
echo "Current Script Owner: ".get_current_user()."\n";
```

return 'www-data' in first string and right user 'correct_user' in second string

Created files has user name - www-data

How to create files with user 'correct_user' owner?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP: get\_current\_user() vs. exec('whoami')](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28548743/php-get-current-user-vs-execwhoami)

Comment: Maybe you can use [chown](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) to change the file's owner after its creation. If that's not an option, maybe to change the user that executes the script (in httpd.conf) is...?